# Guitar song from the movie The Town That Dreaded Sundown (2014)

Tags: identify-this-song

In the movie *The Town That Dreaded Sundown* (2014), there is a scene where the sheriff is alone with a girl, and he puts a tape on and one of the best bluesy intros to a song I have ever heard comes on, but I cannot identify the track.

The video is Not Safe For Work, but can be found [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHX27FK5Q9c).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to verify which song it is exactly, but there is a list of songs mentioned at the credits. Who performed which one is not readable on my copy.

- Goodnight Sweet Dream
- Jesus Christ
- Two Hearts Entwine
- A New York Love
- Happy Call
- God Rest Ye Merry Gentlemen
- Silent Night
- Your Other Man

Other relevant writers/composers in that movie are Jaime Mendoza-Nava and Ludwig Göransson.

While not a definitive answer, I do trust this list will help you find the track you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks For Your Input Mast, I Have Just Sat And Gone The Credits And Typed Every Song Into You tube And None Of Them Are The Track I am Looking For? Im Truly Stumped With This One!!

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely either a song that was recorded in the studio specifically for the movie or possibly a stock music track that isn't required to be credited. See the following Blues Acoustic track for an example:

https://motionarray.com/stock-music/acoustic-blues-11635

There are many stock music tracks out there that are commonly used in movies and television because they are less expensive than paying a studio royalties to use an official song.